# Create regex from string javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a question regarding creating a regex from a string. The code is in javascript, basically a variable gets a string. I am not sure how to convert the string to the regex. Here is the code

```
  var string = "the code";
  var regex = /(the |code )/g;
```

How can I convert my string to regex using javascript?

Comment: You want to extract the pattern from the string?

Comment: What are you going to do with the regexp once you have it?

Comment: I feel you are looking for hole word matching. I'd use `/\b(?:the|code)\b/g`. Then, `var myRegex = new RegExp('\\b(?:' + str.replace(/ /g,'|') + ')\\b','g');`. Or a more universal:  `var myRegex = new RegExp('(^|\\W)(?:' + str.replace(/ /g,'|') + ')(?!\\w)','g');`.

Answer (score 6):

use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
var stringRe = "the code";
var re = new RegExp(stringRe, "g");
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor, like this:

```
var regex = new RegExp(str, 'g');
```

Comment: The OP may or may not know how to use the RegExp constructor, but it seems pretty clear he wants to create a regexp to look for any of the words in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var str = "the code";
var myRegex = new RegExp('(' + str.replace(' ','|') + ')','g');
```

Comment: `myRegex` is `/(the|code)/g` - not what is expected.

Comment: What do the parentheses do?

Comment: @stribizhev, good point. I was just giving him a way to create the regex he specified in his question.

Comment: no need for parenthesis here

Comment: @vstepaniuk, please see my comment immediately above yours.